# Check the continuity of the function for all points in its domain

Tags: continuity

$$ F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x + 1 & \text{for }x < 1 \\
0 & \text{for }1 \leq  x < 2 \\
2-x & \text{for }x \geq 2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: At $x=1$ there is a jump from $2$ to $0$, so it's discontinuous at $x=1$. At all other places the function is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to analyze two points :

- When $x = 1$ : $\lim_{x\to 1^-} F(x) = 2$, $\ \lim_{x\to 1^+} F(x) = 0$
- When $x = 2$ : $\lim_{x\to 2^-} F(x) = 0$, $\ \lim_{x\to 2^+} F(x) = 0$

Can you conclude ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the boundaries between the intervals $(x=1, x=2)$ where it has already been demonstrated that there is a discontinuity at $x=1$, according to your question you also need to consider *all* other $x$.

Since the function is comprised piecewise of 2 polynomials and a constant, which are continuous on their domains, it is true that $F(x)$ is continuous at all other values of $x$